# Download avatars of people and display them in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, file-transfer

Recently I became really interested in making of my own chat in node.js. I've already done many things (such as registration and login), but I got stuck at one problem: I need to display avatars of people in the friend list, which would look something like this:
[test friend list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8mPe.png)
Those gray circles are an img tags (this will be default empty image), and they should be replaced by avatars. However, I don't know what is the correct way of sending image to a client by request. I'm using socket.io in order to communicate and send JSONs, but I believe you can't send images (or files?) via socket.io. The only information I found on the internet was about uploading files to the server using AJAX request, which is useful but still not telling me how to ask a server for a picture.

```
var id = 0;

function addFriendElement() {
  $().add(
    '<div class="personTab" onclick="makeActive(this);">' +
    '<div class ="smallAvatar"><img src="img/testAvatar.png" alt="No avatar?"></div>' +
    '<div class ="nickname">' + id + '</div>' +
    '</div>').appendTo("#friendList");
  id++;
}
```

This is how I add those "tabs" you've seen in the screenshot. I wonder if using an img tag is not correct as well.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to send the image from the server to the browser.

Just need to make avatar's URL (what is set in *src* attribute of *img* tag) accessible via HTTP from the browser (maybe as static assets).

If you are using ExpressJs, [here is the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I always thought that "static" means it will only load once and will remain with these files, I should have tried it at least once. Thank you very much! I'll try it right now

Comment: Thank you very much! I really should have tried myself. Thank you for wasting a bit of your time :P